# Is there a compatible version of Asp.Net Membership system with SQL Server 2016?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-membership, upgrade

We ran a compatibility test between our SQL Server 2012 and SQL Server 2016. We ran into several Unqualified Join(s) detected issues. All of them came from `dbo.aspnet_Membership_XXX` stored procedures. Examples are `aspnet_Membership_ChangePasswordQuestionAndAnswer` and `aspnet_Membership_FindUsersByEmail`.

The application we are using is not likely to be updated to use identity, or another provider, but we would like to get our servers up to date. Is there a supported fix for this incompatibility?

**Edit**: further, there are Deprecated data types TEXT, IMAGE or NTEXT warnings, which have recommendations that begin with:

> Deprecated data types are marked to be discontinued on next versions of SQL Server.

However the tables with the issue are in the `aspnet_Membership` schema, like `aspnet_Membership.Comment` and `aspnet_PersonalizationPerUser.PageSettings`.

Comment: What is your current database compatibility level?

Comment: Currently, we are at 110, but when we upgrade, we would like to go to 130

Comment: Have you found an upgrade sqlscript to fix the compatibility issue? Or have you created it yourself?

Comment: We decided to just leave it alone.